# Haskell: applying flip twice (type of flip flip)

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I am learning Haskell along some basic functions. I was doing some exercises with Flip, which takes a function of two arguments and evaluates the result flipping the order of the arguments. Consider the function **flip flip**, I would have thought, following the definition of flip, that it flipped the arguments twice, evaluating the original function with the parameters in the original order. When I checked this assumption with ghci checking the function type, it yielded:

flip flip :: b -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> c

I don't understand why this is the function type of flip flip. It takes parameter b and parameter (a -> b -> c) and yields a function a -> c. Why is this the case ? I would really appreciate an explanation since I am at lost with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not flip twice, you flip the `flip` function.

Comment: And just for fun, try `flip flip flip`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flipping twice would be `\f -> flip (flip f)`, or `flip . flip`. This would indeed have the type `(a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c)`.

What you are doing here instead is applying `flip` on the `flip` function, i.e. flipping `flip`'s argument order. So if we start with

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
-- and, as the type of the argument
flip :: (a' -> b' -> c') -> b' -> a' -> c'
```

then if we match the types

```
a = (a' -> b' -> c')
b = b'
c = a' -> c'
```

we get the result

```
flip flip :: b' -> (a' -> b' -> c') -> (a' -> c')
```

Comment: Thanks for your succint answer. I realized I don't quite get one thing still (sorry if this question sound pretty trivial but I am completely new to Haskell). Why did you match " b = b' " and not " b = (b'->a') " and then " c = c' " ? Why is the first association the valid one and not the other I gave ?

Comment: Because of the right-associativity of the `->` syntax. Spelled out explicitly, the type is `((a -> (b -> (c))) -> (b -> (a -> (c))))`. All functions in Haskell are unary in fact (taking only a single argument), they just might return another function that again takes another argument. The type `(b' -> (a' -> c'))` is different from `((b' -> a') -> c')`, they just don't match.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at the types:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> (a -> c)
flip :: (d            -> e ->  f     ) -> e ->  d            ->  f
flip flip ::                              b -> (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> c)
```

In other words, `flip` reverses the first two arguments of its argument, and the first two arguments of `flip` are the function to flip and the second argument to that function. So instead of taking arguments in the order 'function', 'second argument', 'first argument', the order becomes 'second argument', 'function', 'first argument' when you flip it.

If you want to flip, and then flip back, you do something like this:

```
doubleflip x = flip (flip x)
```

Or equivalently:

```
doubleflip = flip . flip
```

The `(.)` operator feeds the output of the right-hand side into the left-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

You do *not* apply the `flip` function twice. If you want to apply `flip` twice, you are looking for:

```
flip . flip :: (b -> a -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

What you here do is *flipping* the `flip` function. So it takes `flip` as the function to `flip`.

We can resolve the type of `flip1 flip2` (I here use subscripts to make it clear to which `flip` we are referring) as:

```
flip1 :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip2 :: (d -> e -> f) -> e -> d -> f
```

Since `flip2` is the parameter of `flip1`, so that means that the type of `flip2` is the same type of the parameter of `flip1`, so that means that:

```
        a       -> (b ->    c    )
~ (d -> e -> f) -> (e -> (d -> f))
```

Hence that means that `a ~ (d -> e -> f)` (the type `a` is the same as `d -> e -> f`), `b ~ e` and `c ~ (d -> e)`. So the type of the function `flip1 flip2` is the type of the output type of `flip1`, but with the equivalences, so that means that:

```
flip1 flip2 :: b -> a -> c
flip1 flip2 :: e -> (d -> e -> f) -> (d -> e)
```

We basically thus made a function that first takes the second parameter, then takes the function, and then the first parameter, and then calls that function with the flipped parameters. So if `flip2 = flip flip`, it is implemented like:

```
flip2 :: e -> (d -> e -> f) -> (d -> e)
flip2 y f x = f x y
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of good and thorough answers here, but I'd just like to add a practical example that shows an expression with `flip flip` being evaluated:

```
     flip flip 2 (>) 4
-->  flip (>) 2 4 
-->  (>) 4 2
-->  True
```

If it helps, you may introduce a pair of parentheses to the original expression so you can really "taste the curry": `(flip flip 2 (>)) 4`.

As to why would you like to do something like that: even though I'm far from a Haskell expert, if for some reason you're determined to write a function in [point-free](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) notation, flipping a flip can come in useful. For instance - in light of the example above - if you wish to define `f` by the equation `f a g b = g b a` then `f = flip flip` (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429150/770765) already points out).